# how to create empty folder into my gallery?

Tags: java, android, gallery, directory

1. How to create folder in gallery
2. 1st I need to create one empty folder in gallery 
   This is my task simple folder creation no need to be share images in my folder, 1st I want view folder in gallery....now my gallery display lot of image....

   ```
   package galleryview.galleryview;

   import java.io.File;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.Environment;
   import android.provider.MediaStore;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
   import android.widget.Gallery;
   import android.widget.GridView;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

   public class Galleryview extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   private Cursor imagecursor, actualimagecursor;
   private int image_column_index, actual_image_column_index;
   GridView imagegrid;
   private int count;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       init_phone_image_grid();
   }
   private void init_phone_image_grid() {
     File mFile=new File("/sdcard/photos/newfolder");
     mFile.mkdir();
       String[] img = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
       imagecursor = managedQuery(
   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, null,
   null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "");
       image_column_index = imagecursor
   .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
       count = imagecursor.getCount();
       imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
       imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
       imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,
    int position, long id) {
                   System.gc();
                   String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                   actualimagecursor = managedQuery(
   MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,
   null, null, null);
                   actual_image_column_index = actualimagecursor
   .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                   actualimagecursor.moveToPosition(position);
                   String i = actualimagecursor.getString(actual_image_column_index);
                   System.gc();
                  // Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  
                  ViewImage.class);
                  //Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                  //intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/"), "images/*");
                  //startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),   
           ViewImage.class);

                  intent.putExtra("filename", i);
                  startActivity(intent);
                                                           }
       });
       }


     public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       private             Context mContext;


         public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
             mContext = c;
       }
       public int getCount() {
             return count;
       }
       public Object getItem(int position) {
             return position;
       }
       public long getItemId(int position) {
             return position;
       }
       public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
             System.gc();
             ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
             if (convertView == null) {
                   imagecursor.moveToPosition(position);
                   int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                   i.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""
   + id));
                   i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                   i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(110,110));
             }
             else {
                   i = (ImageView) convertView;
             }
             return i;
       }
    }
       }
   ```

Comment: Not sure, but it may be empty folders may not work - it may be that a folder won't show up in gallery until the media scanner has found some images in it.  The folder would still be there on the underlying storage, just not displayed by media-oriented applications until something relevant has been found in it.

Answer (score 0):

for create new folder in sdcard..

```
File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/NewFolder/");
wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
```